# Is $\mathbb{Q}$ a principal ideal domain?

Tags: principal-ideal-domains

Is $\mathbb{Q}$ a principal ideal domain? I know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is, but I'm not sure about $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is. Every field is a principal ideal domain, since it has no non-trivial ideals.

Comment: More precisely, the ideals of a field are all principal: $(0)$, $(1)$.